# Converting from ESRI Shapefile to Aircom Asset data format

Tags: shapefile, convert, vector-layer

I've shapefile contains vector layer of 3D buildings with their Z values.

I'm looking for help to convert this file to AIRCOM International’s ENTERPRISE format. The aim is to use converted vector data in Asset planning tool

Any tool or programmatic/Python solution is welcome

Comment: This website advertises a program that can convert Aircom enterprise files to shapefile. Maybe it can do the reverse. https://www.safe.com/integrate/aircom-enterprise-map-data-asset-data/

Comment: Yes, FME will convert Shape to AIRCOM. Download an eval copy  at https://www.safe.com/fme/fme-desktop/trial-download/ (nb: I work for Safe Software. Other solutions may exist!)